# Evaluating $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I got to evaluate this series, this is my approach ($n\in \mathbb{Z^+}$)
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)^n}, \text{ let } k+1=b, \sum_{b=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{b-1}}{b^n}= -\sum_{b=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{b}}{b^n} = -\operatorname{Li}_n(-1)$$
But I'm not sure if this is how it's done.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: This is simply $\eta(n)$, using the [Dirichlet eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function).

Comment: Your result is correct. It is also $\left(1-2^{1-n}\right) \zeta (n)$